# Same equation, different answers from Pylab and Octave

Tags: python, matlab, octave, equation, matplotlib

I am porting code created in octave into pylab.  One of the ported equations gives dramatically different results in python than it does in octave.

The best way to explain is to show plots generated by octave and pylab from the same equation.

Here is a simplified snippet of the original equation in octave.  In this small test script, the result of function with phi held at zero is plotted from ~ (-pi,pi):

```ml
clear
clc
close all

L1 = 4.25; % left servo arm length
L2 = 5.75; % left linkage length
L3 = 5.75; % right linkage length
L4 = 4.25; % right servo arm length
L5 = 11/2; % distance from origin to left servo
L6 = 11/2; % distance from origin to right servo

theta_array = [-pi+0.1:0.01:pi-0.1];
phi = 0/180*pi;

for i = 1 : length(theta_array)

theta = theta_array(i);

A(i) = -L3*(-((2*cos(theta)*L1*(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)-2*sin(theta)*L1*(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1))/(2*L3*sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2))-((2*sin(theta)*L1*(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)-2*cos(theta)*L1*(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1))*(-(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2-(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2-L3^2+L2^2))/(4*L3*((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)^(3/2)))/sqrt(1-(-(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2-(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2-L3^2+L2^2)^2/(4*L3^2*((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)))-((cos(theta)*L1)/sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)-((sin(theta)*L1-sin(phi)*L4)*(2*sin(theta)*L1*(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)-2*cos(theta)*L1*(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)))/(2*((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)^(3/2)))/sqrt(1-(sin(theta)*L1-sin(phi)*L4)^2/((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)))*sin(acos((-(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2-(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2-L3^2+L2^2)/(2*L3*sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)))-asin((sin(theta)*L1-sin(phi)*L4)/sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)^2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)^2)));

end

plot(theta_array,A)
```

The resulting octave plot looks like this:

[image: Octave result]

The same equation was copied and pasted from octave into python with '^' replaced with '**', 'acos' replaced with 'arccos', and 'asin' replaced with 'arcsin'.  The same range of theta was plotted with phi held at zero:

```py
from pylab import *

# physical setup
L1 = 4.25; # left servo arm length
L2 = 5.75; # left linkage length
L3 = 5.75; # right linkage length
L4 = 4.25; # right servo arm length
L5 = 11.0/2.0; # distance from origin to left servo
L6 = 11.0/2.0; # distance from origin to right servo

theta = arange(-pi+0.1,pi-0.1,0.01);
phi = 0/180.0*pi

def func(theta,phi):

A = -L3*(-((2*cos(theta)*L1*(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)-2*sin(theta)*L1*(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1))/(2*L3*sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2))-((2*sin(theta)*L1*(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)-2*cos(theta)*L1*(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1))*(-(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2-(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2-L3**2+L2**2))/(4*L3*((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)**(3/2)))/sqrt(1-(-(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2-(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2-L3**2+L2**2)**2/(4*L3**2*((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)))-((cos(theta)*L1)/sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin((phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)-((sin(theta)*L1-sin(phi)*L4)*(2*sin(theta)*L1*(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)-2*cos(theta)*L1*(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)))/(2*((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)**(3/2)))/sqrt(1-(sin(theta)*L1-sin(phi)*L4)**2/((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)))*sin(arccos((-(L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2-(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2-L3**2+L2**2)/(2*L3*sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)))-arcsin((sin(theta)*L1-sin(phi)*L4)/sqrt((L6+L5-cos(phi)*L4-cos(theta)*L1)**2+(sin(phi)*L4-sin(theta)*L1)**2)))

return A

f = figure();
a = f.add_subplot(111);

a.plot(theta,func(theta,phi))

ginput(1, timeout=-1); # wait for user to click so we dont lose the plot
```

Python's result looks like this:
[image: Python result]

I cant determine what is causing the differences, Any ideas?

Comment: Those functions are the _simplified_ versions of the original function? Wow. Any chance you could knock off identical chunks from both pieces one at a time and try to find something smaller still? :)

Comment: Given the complexity of the function, could it be an issue of different floating-point precision and/or rounding errors?  Have you tried plotting smaller parts of the function to narrow down the cause?

Comment: Its simplified in the sense that all extraneous code was taken out to simplify the problem for the stack overflow Gurus.

Comment: With regard to floating point / rounding errors, I *believe* that octave and python use the same size (double precision) when performing calculations. Truthfully, it *is* a complicated equation and I am not dismissing floating precision / round off / order of operations error

Comment: tl;dr in python, 3/2 = 1, in matlab 3/2 = 1.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `from __future__ import division` to eliminate errors arising from floor division.

Comment: Huzzah!  Thank you! that seems to have fixed it.  Are there any other math gotchas I should look out for?

Comment: @Inverse_Jacobian:  If this answer solves your problem, you should accept it (click on the check-mark by it).